# Flask Class views and Blueprints test case failure

Tags: python, json, flask, sqlalchemy

I am working on a Flask class views and blueprints problem wherein routes needs to be created for adding and listing the students to and from the db. Not able to pass the tests. the failure says

```
TypeError: <StudentModel 1> is not JSON serializable
```

Not sure if this is the correct way to approach the problem. Kindly guide

StudentView.py

```
from flask import request, json, Response, Blueprint,jsonify
from flask import render_template
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from ..models.StudentModel import StudentModel, StudentSchema

#Add your code here
stu =Blueprint('stu', __name__,url_prefix='/api/students')
# Create routes to add a student to the database.
@stu.route('/add',methods=['POST'])
def add():

    r = request.json
    id = r['id']
    student_name=r['student_name']
    student_age=r['student_age']
    sm =StudentModel(r)
    sm.update(r)
    sm.save()
    x=sm.get_student_id(id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        return Response(json.dumps(r),status= 201)
    
# Create routes to list all the added students

@stu.route('/')
def getstudents():
  users =StudentModel.query.all()
  return jsonify(users)
```

StudentModel.py

```
class StudentModel(db.Model):
  
  #Table name
  __tablename__ = 'student'

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  student_name = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
  student_age = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
  

  #class constructor
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.id = data.get('id')
    self.student_name = data.get('student_name')
    self.student_age= data.get('student_age')


  def save(self):
    db.session.add(self)
    db.session.commit()

  def update(self, data):
    for key, item in data.items():
      setattr(self, key, item)
    db.session.commit()

  def delete(self):
    db.session.delete(self)
    db.session.commit()

  @staticmethod
  def get_all_students():
    return StudentModel.query.all()

  @staticmethod
  def get_student_id(id):
    return StudentModel.query.filter_by(id=id).first()

  def __repr(self):
      return '<id {}>'.format(self.id)


class StudentSchema(Schema):
  id = fields.Int(required=True)
  student_name= fields.Str(required=True)
  student_age = fields.Int(required=True)
```

app.py

```
from src.views.StudentView import stu
app.register_blueprint(stu)
```

test.py

```
import pytest
from api import app, db
import json
import base64
from flask import Flask
import os
from src.models.StudentModel import StudentModel
from src.models.TeacherModel import TeacherModel

class Test_API:
    client  = app.test_client()
    
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='session')
    def setUp(self):
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///testing.db'
        db.create_all()
        yield db
        os.remove('testing.db')

    def test_student_in_db(self):
        result  = StudentModel.query.all()
        assert len(result) == 0
        assert result == []

    def test_students_list(self):
        url = "api/students/"
        response = self.client.get(url)
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert response.json == []

    def test_students_register_method(self):
        url = "/api/students/add"
        payload = '{"id": 1,"student_age": 16 , "student_name": "testname"}'
        headers = { 'Content-Type': "application/json",  'cache-control': "no-cache"  }
        response = self.client.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
        assert response.status_code == 201
        assert response.json['message'] == 'Added student to the list'
        
    
    def test_data_in_db_after_adding(self):
        result  = StudentModel.query.all()
        assert len(result) == 1
        assert result[0].student_name == 'testname'


    def test_after_adding_students(self):
        url = "api/students/"
        response = self.client.get(url)
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert response.json == [{'id': 1, 'student_age': 16, 'student_name': 'testname'}]
```

test failures:

Test_API.test_after_adding_students _________________________________

```
self = <tests.tests_routes.Test_API object at 0x7fb88ce5df98>

    def test_after_adding_students(self):
        url = "api/students/"
>       response = self.client.get(url)

tests/tests_routes.py:49: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py:1006: in get
    return self.open(*args, **kw)
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/testing.py:227: in open
    follow_redirects=follow_redirects,
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py:970: in open
    response = self.run_wsgi_app(environ.copy(), buffered=buffered)
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py:861: in run_wsgi_app
    rv = run_wsgi_app(self.application, environ, buffered=buffered)
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py:1096: in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py:2463: in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py:2449: in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py:1866: in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py:39: in reraise
    raise value
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py:2446: in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py:1951: in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py:1820: in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py:39: in reraise
    raise value
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py:1949: in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py:1935: in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
src/views/StudentView.py:39: in getstudents
    return jsonify(users)
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py:370: in jsonify
    dumps(data, indent=indent, separators=separators) + "\n",
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py:211: in dumps
    rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py:237: in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py:198: in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py:256: in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py:100: in default
    return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <flask.json.JSONEncoder object at 0x7fb88ce241d0>, o = <StudentModel 1>

    def default(self, o):
        """Implement this method in a subclass such that it returns
        a serializable object for ``o``, or calls the base implementation
        (to raise a ``TypeError``).
    
        For example, to support arbitrary iterators, you could
        implement default like this::
    
            def default(self, o):
                try:
                    iterable = iter(o)
                except TypeError:
                    pass
                else:
                    return list(iterable)
                # Let the base class default method raise the TypeError
                return JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
    
        """
>       raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
E       TypeError: <StudentModel 1> is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
from flask import request, json, Response, Blueprint
from flask import render_template
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from ..models.StudentModel import StudentModel, StudentSchema

#Add your code here
stu= Blueprint('student', __name__, url_prefix="/api/students")

# Create routes to add a student to the database.
@stu.route('/add',methods=['POST'])
def add():
    if request.method=='POST':
        r = request.get_json()
        sm =StudentModel(r)
        sm.update(r)
        sm.save()
 
        resp = json.jsonify({'message': "Added student to the list"})
        resp.status_code = 201
        return resp


# Create routes to list all the added students
@stu.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def view():
    studs = StudentModel.get_all_students()
    res = [{'id':s.id, 'student_name':s.student_name, 'student_age':s.student_age} for s in studs]
    return json.jsonify(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to approach the problem is going through the errors one by one.

The first error is from a test that checks whether the response of adding a new student is the HTTP code 201 (Created), but instead your code returns 200 (Ok). The reason your code returns 200 is because that's the default of Flask if you do not specify anything else (and if there are no errors in processing the request). To solve this one, search the web for how to return custom http codes in Flask.

The second error comes from a test that expects this one previously added student to come up when querying all students. Technically this test depends on the first test that first adds the student. The reason this test fails is because in your `add` function there is no interaction with the database. Check the methods on `StudentModel` and try to use the request data to create a new entry in your database. Good google keywords here are "SQLAlchemy insert" or "SQLAlchemy save new object to database".

Once you fix the second error, the third error should also go away. It also tests whether the user was added, but goes one step further by using the API to get the users, and it also checks whether the correct user data was used.

The remaining tests work very similarly, just for teachers rather than students.

Comment: Thanks @Hubert. I was able to pass  2 test cases with the help of your input. However, I am stuck with `test_after_adding_students`. Tried using the methods defined in `StudentModel.py`. Test case fails with `TypeError: <StudentModel 1> is not JSON serializable` error

Comment: Hey @lazyEval, it's a little confusing when you change your question where the problem is now a completely different one. I suggest you try to narrow down the problem to the relevant pieces of code and ask a new question. That way, no context gets lost in the edits.

Comment: Sure @Hubert will do that.